Algorithm CART in R: Where are the Decision Trees' cross-validation error costs?
I was making a Decision Tree. I used the following code:
CPUE <- read.csv("CPUE_C1_11.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ";", dec = ".")

Everything in my data is numerical, they are seen as following:

When I wanted to see how the variables are dealt with CPUEt_m3.h by means of a Decision tree, it's only shown as following:
mCPUE1 <- rpart(CPUEt_m3.h ~ ., data=CPUE, method="anova")


mCPUE1
n= 25
node), split, n, deviance, yval
* denotes terminal node

root 25 0.0011435000  0.02680000
C9u< 622.4586 18 0.0002807778  0.02338889 *
C9u>=622.4586 7 0.0001147143  0.03557143 *


Plotting:
rpart.plot(mCPUE1, type=3, digits=3, fallen.leaves=TRUE)


CPUEt_m3.h depends on 22 variables.
Is it possible to see cross-validation error cost (CV-cost) and the cost of validation on the training sample (Resubstitution cost) to decide which Decision tree represents better my dependent variable?.
Here is my data:
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/7sgyqsa06zv2n9nvw9ath/CPUE_C1_11.csv?rlkey=qphkxc6ogu2lnjbicj27lr3sp&st=cj92aewj&dl=0
